# Specified cast is not valid when I try to cast to (int?)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this code to save data to database

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = dt.Rows[i];

            await stock.AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest(Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantité"]),
                (int?)row["Filetage"],
                Convert.ToInt32(row["idProject"]),
                (int?)row["idCategory"],
                (int?)row["idType"]).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
```

and this the code behind  AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest

```
public async Task AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest(int Quantity, int? Filetage, int IdProject, int? IdCategory, int? IdType)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        await Task.Run(() => DAL.Open()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];

        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = Quantity
        };

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Filetage", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = Filetage.HasValue ? Filetage : (object)DBNull.Value
        };

        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@IdProject", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = IdProject
        };

        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@IdCategory", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = IdCategory.HasValue ? IdCategory : (object)DBNull.Value
        };

        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@IdType", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = IdType.HasValue ? IdType : (object)DBNull.Value
        };

        await Task.Run(() => DAL.ExcuteCommande("AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest", param)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        DAL.Close();

    }
```

and this is my stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest
        @Quantity int
       ,@Filetage int
       ,@IdProject int
       ,@IdCategory int
       ,@IdType int
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProjectNeedsBolts]
       ([Quantity]
       ,[Filetage]
       ,[IdProject]
       ,[IdCategory]
       ,[IdType])
 VALUES
       (@Quantity
       ,@Filetage
       ,@IdProject
       ,@IdCategory
       ,@IdType)
```

Now when I click on save button I get this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Smart Industrial Management.exe but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

On debugging on this line of code

```
(int?)row["Filetage"]
```

I get this error message

> Cannot unbox 'row["Filetage"]' as a 'int?'

Update:This is my datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    void CreateDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantité");
        dt.Columns.Add("Filetage");
        dt.Columns.Add("idProject");
        dt.Columns.Add("idCategory");
        dt.Columns.Add("idType");

        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

If I try with

```
dt.Columns.Add("Filetage", typeof(int?));
```

I get error message

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>

Comment: So... what's in `row["Filetage"]`

Comment: @TheGeneral it can hold int value or null

Comment: Thats the assumption, have you inspected the value ?

Comment: explicitly: what is `row["Filetage"].GetType().FullName` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell "System.String"

Comment: @TheGeneral I try on debugging I get error message Cannot unbox 'row["Filetage"]' as a 'int?'

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah well, yeah; you can't cast a `string` to an `int?` - it sounds to me like your database schema is horribly wrong - the column should be `int` if it represents an `int`; if you can't change that, you'll have to expect string, and do your own formatting (remembering to think about what culture the data is stored in, which might not be the same as the culture on the running machine, or the culture of the database server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `DataTable` doesn't support `int?` - you'd add it as an `int` - with `DataTable` handing nullability *separately*. For the cast, there are two possibilities:

1. the value is `DBNull`
2. the value is something else - not an `int`; perhaps a `long` or a `string`

For 1 - just check whether the value `is DBNull`, and if so: don't try casting it to an int - handle the `null` yourself.

For 2 - you'd have to do your own parsing / conversion code, but frankly: it would be better to fix the database so that it *is right*

However, frankly: I am going to say: tools like Dapper make this just go away - no `DataTable`, no worries. You'd just use things like a `List<ProjectNeedsBolts>` for POCO:

```cs
public class ProjectNeedsBolts {
    public int Quantity {get;set;}

    public int IdType {get;set;}
}
```

(or `int?`, or whatever else you need), then get the library to do all the work for you:

```cs
await conn.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(
    "AddProjectNeedsBoltsTest",
    new { Quantity, Filetage, IdProject, IdCategory, IdType }
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or:

```cs
var data = await conn.QueryAsync<ProjectNeedsBolts>(
    "your select sql",
    new {...} // parameters
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Yes I already start to learn Dapper ,if you can recommend any course particularly for winform I will be grateful